# Light Detection and Ranging (LIDAR) Range Bias Compensation with Light Dependent Resistor (LDR)

Tags: noise, radar

I have a distance sensor ([VL53L0X](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vl53l0x.pdf)), which measures the distance to an object. It is placed outside. I currently do 100 measurements in the best available range mode, then I take the median and insert it to a database.

The current distance is about 1m.

This is how it looks like during a period af about 12 hours. As can be seen there is a light dependent error in the data.

I also have a LDR (light dependent resistor) output (log scale on y-axis), which shows this more. At "peak" time the error is about 15cm.

[image: plot]

Green: distance in meters, yellow, Voltage from LDR (light dependent resistor). The darker it gets, the higher the voltage of the LDR. At night it's about 2.5V.

Now, the distance hasn't changed in those 12 hours. My question is: how can I compensate this error? I am looking for a term on how this procedure is called.

My first guess was to calculate the difference to 1m for all distance points, then maybe fit the LDR output to that error points.

Data: https://pastebin.com/2fXcSUQB

Column 1: distance in meters, Column 2: voltage from LDR

Comment: Is it possible to post the data of the two curves?

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes, I will upload them in a few minutes.

Comment: sorry, took longer. It's uploaded now.

Comment: Could you explain what we see? I don't under stand what is the data you are showing. I can tell it is a range measurement but I don't understand the yellow line (What's LDR)? Please read again your question and try make it clearer.

Comment: clarified it a bit

Comment: You can always [match the means and standard deviations of the two](https://imgur.com/a/tfGcUnA) which ideally would align them. But as you can see, the LIDAR signal does not exactly follow the LDR and any attempt at correcting one with the other would introduce further errors (see for example that little hump on the LIDAR, or that sharp drop in the LDR as it begins to decrease in value). What is the material of the LIDAR target? What is the power supply of the LIDAR? This might not be light dependent exactly... It might be temperature related.

Comment: I would only try to correct the values during daytime (+ some offset). Material is snow. I have looked at the temperature curve too, but it doesn't match as "nicely" as the LDR values. Would a temperature correction not be the same technique as this one?

Comment: And [this](https://imgur.com/a/vePMUdw) is the kind of correction we are talking about. Not a huge improvement.

Comment: This would be the temperature curve: https://i.imgur.com/wLaXGo6.png

Comment: Well, there is a positive trend in the LIDAR as you can see. At -3, snow cannot have melted (to explain the dip). But the LIDAR shows a positive almost linear increase and at the end of the plot is a bit higher than where it started. Was there any additional snowfall? Is it possible to try pointing to concrete or a piece of wood as a comparison?

Comment: There was no snowfall, and no melting that would account for ~15 cm. How did you correct it in your picture?

Comment: have you tried using a ANOVA model fit?

Comment: Cant you extract the information of the light (sunlight), I would assume that the noise changes during the day, taking this into account you would have more information to explain the error. Somehow you have to estimate the distance from the data your sensor measures, have a look also at recieved data and see if you have to adjust your distance approximation depending on the noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would like to explain the LIDAR signal as a combination of one or more other variables, here LDR and/or Temperature and then remove the effect of those variables from the LIDAR signal.

The first part can be achieved with linear (hopefully) regression and specifically [Multiple Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Simple_and_multiple_linear_regression) where you would be fitting a model like `LIDAR = Constant + LDR_Coef * LDR + Temp_Coef * Temp`.

With the availability of just the LDR data (code in [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) but easily transferable to other platforms too):

```
%Load the data
D = dlmread("myfile.txt",";"); %myfile.txt is the file you provided which is delimited by semicolon.
% Adjust the LDR signal
D(:,3) = log(D(:,3));
% Fit the model using regress.
% For more information see: https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/regress.html
[B, BINT, R, RINT, STATS] = regress(D(:,2), [ones(size(D(:,3))), D(:,3)]);
```

After you do this, you get your model coefficients in `B` and a few other things (more about this later on).

It is now possible to express LIDAR as a function of LDR:

```
% Plot LIDAR and LIDAR as a function of LDR
r=0:(length(D)-1);
plot(r,D(:,2),B(1)+B(2).*D(:,3));
xlabel('Time');ylabel('LIDAR / LDR');legend('LIDAR','LDR');grid on;
```

This now looks like:

[image]

This concludes with the fitting part. Now we want to remove the variation due to LDR, which is the "easy" part:

```
LIDAR_adjusted = D(:,2) - B(2).*D(:,3);
plot(r,D(:,2),LIDAR_adjusted);
xlabel('Time');ylabel('LIDAR');legend('LIDAR','LIDAR_adjusted');grid on;
```

Which results in:

[image]

The `STATS` vector contains [a number of coefficients](https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/regress.html) that inform you about how good is this fit. In this case `7.6591e-01   1.4952e+03   0.0000e+00   7.8229e-04`. So, the $R^2$ is not ideal but not too bad too (that is the first number, it can be between $0$ and $1$ and it is ideal at $1$), the rest of the numbers are not bad too (the error is very small), but if you look at the residuals (that is the difference between the LIDAR and the LIDAR as a function of LDR) it is not exactly noise. Here is the residual (`R`):

```
plot(R);grid on;
```

Which results in:

[image]

There are clearly trends in the residual which means that LDR on its own cannot explain the variation in the LIDAR signal. You can add 'r' as a regressor in there, which would return three coefficients for the model `LIDAR = B(1) + B(2)*D(:,3) + B(3)*r` and that would "take away" that linear upwards trend as a function of time and improve the error but you still get those two humps because the sensor responses are non-linear.

To conclude with this, if you wanted to add the temperature to the model too, just change the `regress` line to:

```
[B, BINT, R, RINT, STATS] = regress(D(:,2), [ones(size(D(:,3)), D(:,3), D(:,4)]);
```

Assuming that you will add another column for the temperature. The rest of the process remains the same (with reasonable adjustments for removing the components further below).

The other thing that you can do of course is a Discrete Fourier Transform (just on the LIDAR) and retain the first few harmonics from it for detrending. The latter assumes that there is a periodic well defined effect of light (and / or temperature and other parameters) on LIDAR which can be approximated with a set of periodic components. And in that case, the adjustment comes as a function of the time of day "for free".

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow, thanks for this answer. just a small question: I get a `syntax error` on the `regress = ...` line in octave 4.4.1

Comment: Ah, I missed closing the bracket on 'ones' in regress :/ edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed post. I took a look at the data today, and to my surprise, it's changed (while the weather hasn't) so I assume this might be some "accllimation issues" with the sensor it self. See this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/bh7Wi00.png while it looks like much due to yrange, the values now vary much less. I will let it run for a few days to see what is happening. After the first day I was convinced that it had a very strong dependence on sunlight, that's why I made this post.

Comment: @fsp No worries, thanks for letting me know. Do you think you could add a black tube of a few cm in front of the sensor to focus the returns to be coming from directly below it? This will smooth out those two humps at the beginning and end and will limit the angle at which the sunlight causes errors to your signal. If you still get errors after that, then temperature might have an involvement too (?). All the best.

Comment: So after a few days, the old pattern started again. So I read the datasheet again. Previously I was confused by their "Ref calibration", I thought I needed to enter the current temperature as parameter, but it turns out it's just some internal mechanism. They recommend recalibrating if the temperature difference is more then 8 °C. I haven't done that, because the difference hasn't been that big. Now I recalibrate every few minutes. If the difference between current and the last value inserted is greater then 5 cm, I also discard that value and recalibrate again.

Comment: @fsp Interesting. I have a VL53L1X, haven't tried it outside though. If you have a simultaneous LDR, Temp set of data we could see if regression could improve things. I suppose that you measure the height of snow (?) Can you protect the sensor at all?

Comment: Yes, the sensor is protected by a wooden structure.

Comment: I'll do that, at the moment those are different tables with different times, which makes merging right now a little cumbersome.